# Searching for value with list in list at once

Tags: python, list

I have a list as in the following image called `Dist_2`. I want to add elements from `Dist` if there are not already in the Dist_2 at position [1:3]

[image: Dist_2]

I cannot find a way to slice the list to check if elements already exist in the list at position [1:3].

I tried

```
for o in range(len(Dist)):
    if Dist[o][1] or Dist[o][2] in Dist_2[:][1:3]:
        continue 
    else:    
        Dist_2.append(Dist[o])
```

The problem is the 'all' command `:`

if I check with a specific row, like:

```
... in Dist_2[0][1:3]
```

I get the results. With `:` I receive following error:

> *** TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

I know it is a silly problem, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

**How to check for the entirety of the list at once?**

---

EDIT:

What I expect is that if I check `Dist_2[:][1:3]`, I would receive all values from all field from the position 1 and 2.

Dist looks like:

```
[[34.438350715445125, 1, 2], [34.9857113690718, 5, 10], ...]
```

so for the first three rows shown in the image, the output should be:

```
1,2,5,10,8,9
```

The Dist list looks quite similar and I append another row if the [1:2] values do not already exist.

p.s. set() cannot be used as I need the order and indices

Comment: are you trying to insert a list in a nested list if that isn't already in it?

Comment: Please post a sample Input and the expected output

Comment: Yes, kind of. I take one row from Dist and append it to Dist_2 if the values from [1:2] do not already are in the Dist_2 list.

Answer (score 0):

It worked using some list comprehension in a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(Dist)): 
    if (Dist[i][1] or Dist[i][2]) in [item for sub_list in Dist_check for item in sub_list]:                        
        continue 
    else:    
        Dist_check.append(Dist[i][1:3])
```